# Why isn't more being done to avoid facilitating copy/paste homework questions?

Tags: discussion, homework

I'm relatively new to this site, but I've noticed a disturbing trend during my time here: many of the questions are simply copy / pasted or even scanned and show little to no effort on the part of the asker.  Personally, I downvote such questions and move on, but it is frustrating to have to sift through the deluge of copy / pasted homework questions to try to find honest questions that are actually worth answering.  Moreover, copy / pasted homework questions are often actually answered, which encourages people to post more and allows them to use Math.SE as a sort of homework answering service.  I have been enjoying Math.SE as a place to ask and answer stimulating questions, and having these hidden among many very low-quality questions makes it less enjoyable.

Just to be clear, I have no problem with elementary questions, provided that they are asked out of honest interest rather than an attempt to outsource one's homework.  This post is about copy / paste questions that show little to no effort on the asker's part.

What are others' thoughts on this?  What can be done to reduce the number of such low-value questions?

There have been some related questions:

[1] [Closing copy-pasted questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1974/closing-copy-pasted-questions)

[2] [homework questions, again](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12644/homework-questions-again)

[3] [Question about PSQ and answering them](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9558/question-about-psq-and-answering-them) (found by someone else)

All of these are at least a year old and since this is an issue that naturally evolves over time I believe a new discussion is warranted.

Comment: Related and somewhat newer than the first link: [1](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9180/proposal-ban-verbatim-homework-questions-which-have-no-accompanying-text), [2](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9201/proposal-discourage-questions-that-are-nothing-besides-a-problem-statement).

Comment: You can flag the questions as missing context. The question will then go into the close queue where 3k user can vote to close it.

Comment: That's fine, but most questions get answered very quickly so the asker still gets their homework solved even if it's closed later.  This in turn encourages more copy / paste questions.

Comment: It's a difficult problem. Even when the question is closed quickly (before an answer is posted), some users still answer in the comments. Recently a user even tried editing closed questions to include the answer (usually with a ridiculous "Is this correct?" at the end), though that was forbidden.

Comment: This is, indeed, a problem. There are two ways regular users can fight this: A) voting to close and delete those threads, B) downvoting those questions and their answers. Neither are ideal, as the whining caused by their applications can be heard all over the site. Method B) would need several users to join forces to be an effective deterrent. Method A) is making some headway, but you need to gain a little bit more reputation to join in the battle. For the time being you can simply flag such questions/answers for low quality.

Comment: (cont'd) That will help push them to the review queues, where more experienced like-minded users can act.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I'll start doing those things once I have enough reputation, but I don't think it is enough to address this problem.  I don't think Method A is enough because the questions get answered before the thread is closed, so the asker still gets the solution.  Method B might work since it might reduce incentive to answer such questions, but homework answers do not seem to be downvoted often.  I'm sure it doesn't help that downvoting answers costs reputation.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen To summarize my previous comment, I think it's clear from the huge number of copy / paste questions on here and the fact that relatively few of them are closed that current methods are not dealing with this problem effectively.

Comment: Correct, Qudit. Unfortunately the idea of entirely banning questions that only want a solution to a homework problem has not won enough support among the users. Therefore I, as a moderator, cannot instadelete them. This has to be a community action, and those take time. Keep on fighting. If you haven't already, check out the [reopen-undelete-close-delete chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2165/reopen-undelete-close-delete). They can give you pointers about how the processes work. Remember to also discuss what not to delete. IMHO some closing criteria are also overused.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen That is a shame.  Instantly deleting them would be great in my opinion.

Comment: One more bit of advice. Do try to leave suggestions for improvements to the question you want to get closed. It is not impossible that somebody posted a bad-looking question simply because they did not know better. We seek to educate those users about the site norms. If the asker seriously wants to learn, they will do something and/or ask for extra pointers, which is also a success.

Comment: (con't) The load of advicing newbies in this way is largely shouldered by the more experienced users, who have been there before, and have prepared comment templates and such for this purpose. So if you don't want to do that yet, don't feel pressured - just FYI.

Comment: I tried leaving comments before the found myself saying the same things over and over.  Is it considered acceptable to paste the same comment repeatedly provided  it is applicable?  I wasn't sure how that would be received.  It is tedious writing essentially the same thing over and over though.  Is that what you meant by comment templates?

Comment: Yes reusing comments is acceptable. There are even [some templates on meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4925/list-of-comment-templates).

Comment: Is it possible to show some bar with additional information to new posters that if it considers an exercise/homework question, it is necessary to provide enough context (e.g. where have you found the problem, why do you want to know the answer to the problem) and show the effort they have already done (which techniques do they think are needed, what have they already tried)? And show this information in a colorful banner, and they need to add a check mark to show that they have read this. And also write that the question will not be answered and downvoted or closed otherwise.

Comment: @Qudit If you find yourself writing the same comment repeatedly, consider making a [pastelet](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/19620/147263) out of it.

Comment: What is a "low value" question? Almost every question poses an opportunity to teach. The question is old news. Please search meta before posting questions.

Comment: @BillDubuque I did and I included some links in my post.

Comment: @Qudit These matters have been discussed many times before. There is no consensus. There never will be. What is the point of continuing to beat the dead horse?

Comment: @BillDubuque The point is to try to create discussion so that the quality of the site can be improved.

Comment: @Qudit If we would show that question considering exercises without research effort are not tolerated, and will not be answered when a new user tries to post a question and needs to put a check mark here, really believe me, the amount of questions with low research effort will decrease. It will be a thousand times more effective than all our downvoting. Of course some will, if you want to IP ban them, go on. They knew the rules, it is their fault then. Now they don't know the rules, who's fault is it then? Maybe ours.

Comment: @Pedro Not necessarily. Google "eternal September".

Comment: But do you guys really believe that most of the people really KNOW they are doing something wrong? Come on, that is the stupiest thing I ever heard. Some don't know how they can ask a question in a proper way. If you show them you have hard rules and show a warning sign etc. most people will behave correctly. I guess you guys also don't misbehave most of the time, why would the new users do misbehave it greatly then? They are just people as us.

Comment: @Pedro These arguments have all been made many times in the past, including the suggestion(s) in your answer.

Comment: So where are we waiting for? As nothing can be put against showing clear rules in order to prevent people from unconsiously abusing the system, and also showing that we are hard for people that really abuse the system. No one can have anything against these things I guess.

With abusing the system defined as posting questions with show no effort at all (in the form of at least pointing out what you already know and have thought of, and or what you have done)

Comment: @pedro If you browsed the earlier discussions you would learn  that many users (including many of the most prolific contributors) do not agree that "effort" needs to be shown.

Comment: I do agree that it should not be shown for conceptual questions and soft questions where this is assumed, but it should be shown for exercises or practical content. Otherwise we become an outsource homework service.

Comment: @BillDubuque Those threads are relatively old.  Views change over time and the established users who commented in this thread (other than you) seem to agree that the deluge of copy/paste homework questions is a problem.

Comment: @Qudit Old does not imply incorrect, and those users are still around and still prolific contributors (though many participate rarely on meta). Meta only represents a small fraction of the community. Some users have no patience for the nonsense that occurs on meta.

Comment: @Bill Dubuque: it is certainly true that a few of the "most prolific contributors" have low quality standards - but this is why it isn't surprising that they are the "most prolific contributors".  *Of course* someone who is willing to answer many poorly-worded questions will gain more points than someone who shows more self-control.

Comment: @CarlMummert Au contraire, what *is* certainly true is that many of the "most prolific contributors" have an "open brain", free of elitist constraints, always happy to generously share their mathematical knowledge with all who ask. My brain is always open - is yours?

Comment: @Bill Dubuque: I think that we should all be careful in trying to assess our own biases. I do think, beyond a certain point, reputation is trivial to earn, and so one cannot use "very high reputation" to measure any sort of real accomplishment apart from time spent farming reputation. Unfortunately, many hastily-composed PSQ posts are ideal cannon fodder for reputation farming (there are a lot of parallels with rep farming in RPG games, actually).

Comment: @Carl I never mentioned "reputation" above so why do you keep mentioning that in your replies?  Do you *really* think that's what motivates many of the most prolific contributors?  Many of them were just as prolific (if not more so) in  other non-gamified repless platforms (sci.math, Ask an Algebraist, etc). This includes most users on the front rep page (except those too young to do so). As prior systems proved beyond a doubt, gamification is not needed to motivate contributions. As such, it makes no sense to presume that question selection is universally correlated with rep farming.

Comment: Why? I don't know. What can be done? I would hope that if someone tries to post a question scanned off the textbook with nothing else, the system would say something like "This needs more details in addition to the graphic."

Comment: @BillDubuque my understanding is that Carl used the points as a proxy for prolificness, which you brought up. It is also trivial to be more prolific. A certain form of prolificness, however, does not add much anything of value (at least in my opinion). In that sense  *I* do not understand why *you* bring up "prolific."

Comment: @quid Of course I do not intend such a trivial denotation of prolificness.

Comment: @BillDubuque to me "prolific" seems to put the focus on quantity. If you want to express something else, please, be more specific.

Comment: @quid In case you are not a native English speaker I will point out that prolific also means fruitful, creative, inventive, etc. That is the denotation that I intend (by no coincidence, many of those users are also prolific quantity-wise - just as they were on other forums such as sci.math).

Comment: @Carl: There's not a user in the top dozen in all-time reputation on MSE who clearly has low standards. There are several whose standards are quite different from yours, which is not at all the same thing.

Comment: @Qudit: Possibly you're too new to know how often a good hint actually results in engagement on the part of the asker, even when the question was quite unpromising. I prefer to give the benefit of the doubt in the first instance. Note that the questions that you don't want to deal with are mostly very easy to spot from title and excerpt, so damn' little real sifting is required.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott do you mean to imply the 13th clearly has low standards? This would not be nice.

Comment: @BillDubuque I am not a native English speaker, and neither are a lot of users of this website. The only dictionary (out of the seven I checked) that has the meaning you intend for "prolific" is Merriam-Webster, which has "marked by abundant inventiveness or productivity" for the *third* definition. You can clearly see that the primary meaning focuses on quantity and nothing else. If you are going to use a word with a very specific meaning, different from what the word means in the overwhelming majority of cases, please reconsider. Some people could find that misleading. Just get to the point.

Comment: @Najib Don't be ridiculous. Simply googling the word instantaneously turns up the various meanings (which are not obscure). And, for the *umpteenth* time, please *stay on topic*. This is not the place for discussing English language, ESL, etc.

Comment: @BillDubuque I'm not discussing the English language, I'm asking you to stop misleading people / communicating poorly and then acting surprised when people misinterpret what you write. I'm also asking you to please be mindful of the diverse audience of your comments. (Seven was not an arbitrary number, I literally googled "define prolific" and clicked on the first seven links.) If you wish I can open a meta thread: "Should users communicate as clearly as possible to accomodate nonnative English speakers on this website?"

Comment: @Najib You are the king of strawman arguments. First, if you search you will see that I have always been a champion of issues related to nonnative speakers. Second, it is quite ridiculous to attack me for using a meaning of a word beyond your English vocabulary, esp. after I quickly explained the intent above as soon as I realized there might be some confusion. For once, could you please try to be more polite, more constructive, and more on-topic?  Failing that I will simply ignore your incessant heckling and unfounded arguments.

Comment: the fact that most folks who answer questions here do not care about format, work-shown etc. is clearly communicated by the fact that we answer said questions. No involvement in meta need communicate our opinion. It is manifest in our actions. We view this site as a platform to help interested students. I really hope we keep it free, freedom is more important than googlable content.

Comment: @James S. Cook: Allowing students to lazily outsource their homework does not actually help them. What they should do instead is ask questions about something that they don't understand in the _method_, i.e. try to learn the concepts required to do the homework, and then go and do their own homework for their own good. In a carefully written question, it shouldn't even be necessary to include the full exercise as an example, if at all.

Comment: Furthermore, the only person that such a question could _really_ help is the student's teacher, who'd then be able to see that the student had _lied_ when they said that they've done their homework. In essence, such students are using SE as a means to deceive their teachers. I.e. Stack Exchange is, as it stands, fuelling their deception.

Comment: @James S. Cook: “googlable content” – Note also that content is _searchable_ by other search engines too, such as [DuckDuckGo](https://duckduckgo.com/) (which, conveniently, has some ‘[bang](https://duckduckgo.com/bang.html)’ shortcuts for SE sites, e.g. !mathse, !se, !use, !so, etc.).

Comment: Having taught a few students, I can tell you, most students are not in the place to ask a well-reasoned question when they do their homework. If seeing a token problem done helps them get past the bump their stuck on then I think we've done a good thing. These students also have to take tests. Anyone who makes homework more than about 10 percent of the total grade is being rather silly in the world which we live. Forget about the MSE, there are complete solution manuals easily found via google etc. I know this as a teacher. Frankly, if a student asked a question about my homework...

Comment: @James Haigh here then I would be delighted. That means they've taken the time to think harder about it than most. Furthermore, if they are really just stealing from the internet without thinking. No matter, I will get them on the test. Don't worry, just help them.

Comment: @James S. Cook: “most students are not in the place to ask a well-reasoned question when they do their homework.” – Sure, I can totally relate to this – it can sometimes be difficult, _even with effort_, to determine exactly what to ask before getting a grasp of the subject, which could be helped by an answer. Often the lack of knowing the correct terminology makes it hard to know what to ask or look for. It can be a bit of a hole-in-my-bucket scenario. However, I think that this meta question is concerned with the homework questions that really are lacking effort (hence the “copy/paste” bit).

Comment: @James S. Cook: And remember, one of the best things that one can teach someone is _how to learn_! …Which in this context becomes ‘[How to ask a homework question?](https://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question)’.

Comment: @quid: Of course not. I simply glanced at the top three rows and took advantage of the fact that *dozen* is a common round number. Were the table laid out in rows of five, I’d probably have used ten.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank you for the clarification. However, it still seems you think there are some (regular) users that have clearly low standards.

Comment: @quid: I can't imagine why you think so; nothing that I've said justifies your conclusion.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott You just claimed you checked the user-page before making your claim. What's the point of doing this if you do not think there are (regular) users with clearly low standards? More generally, what's the point of restricting your claim to only the first few users?

Comment: As long as there are 'rep' points to be had by answering questions, there will be answers to questions, regardless of 'quality'. 'Do my homework' users will not be fazed by down votes or closing, so there is really little you can do to stem the flow. The only 'solution' I see is to vet questions before 'rep' points can be gained by answering them. However, that is a lot of work. Alternatively, the questions could be made public immediately, but the 'rep' to be gained by answering set to zero until the question is examined and deemed 'rep worthy'.

Comment: @quid: Carl’s statement was specifically about ‘a few of the “most prolific contributors”’, and I was responding to that statement. I checked the page because I didn’t want to include anyone whose standards I couldn’t easily defend to others — not to myself — if pressed. In any case, if you want to jump on someone, why aren’t you jumping on him? You can point to his explicit statement that some of those users have low standards instead of making extremely shaky inferences from what I *didn’t* say.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Could you please refrain from encouraging users to jump at others users. Now, I am not easy to influence, so no harm is done, but in general it seems like a bad idea. The issue I see with your statement is precisely that it at first it *looks like* a precise assertion but leaves a lot more unsaid and open to interpretation than it answers.

Comment: @quid: You didn’t answer my very legitimate question. And your holier-than-thou pose is getting awfully threadbare.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I am not sure what you mean. I explained the issue I have with your statement and why I ask for clarification, namely "at first it looks like a precise assertion but leaves a lot more unsaid and open to interpretation than it answers." First, I do not see this issue with Carl's statement so I do not ask him for any clarification.  Or, at least I feel I understand better what he wanted to express so there is less need to ask for clarification.

Comment: Do you also have objections with paying a tutor to help you answer questions you haven't shown any effort in solving, or is it only a problem if it's free?

Comment: @MattSamuel I think OP makes it clear where the objection comes from: having very low-quality questions makes the site less enjoyable. Personally, I don't care how students get their homework done, but I do want to keep garbage off Stack Exchange.

Comment: @MattSamuel In addition to what Woodface says, there's also a big difference between getting _help_ with a problem and posting a scan of the question here so that the answer can just be _copied_.  As for showing effort, it's generally considered rude to ask questions online (or offline for that matter) if you haven't already tried to find the answer yourself.

Comment: If you think it's rude then you are easily offended.

Comment: @MattSamuel How could asking others to spend their time on something you won't spend your own time on be anything but rude?

Comment: Should attempt to remove their own appendix before daring to ask a doctor to do it?

Comment: @MattSamuel Math questions and surgery are quite different, as I'm sure you're aware.

Comment: @Qudit [Not always :)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surgery_theory)

Comment: @Najib Idrissi That's amusing :)  Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I agree that not enough is being done to control the flood of low quality questions.

One problem is that users don't downvote enough. Your 152 downvotes already put you in top 200 downvoters all-time. Only 50 users have cast 500 downvotes or more -- on the site with  about 600 questions arriving *daily*. As a side illustration, here is the distribution of downvotes among these 50 users:

[image: downvotes]

Downvotes (and closevotes) feed automatic systems that can ask users to [wait a day or more before asking another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/asking-rate-limited) or even [ban then from asking](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans). They do work, but they need more input in the form of votes.

Meanwhile, Stack Exchange is working on a new way to handle questions: [triage queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/278380/3717023). So far it is active only on Stack Overflow, but may be expanded to other SE sites when it's fully operational. One of its ideas is that incoming questions are reviewed *before* being made publicly visible. The worst of the questions will proceed into Close queue without appearing on the site and therefore without getting answers. The system isn't yet fully implemented even on Stack Overflow, but it shows promise; I participate in triage over there and like the way it works.

Comment: I don't believe downvoting is really an option. We get new users every day. And also, many people forget to write down why exactly the person is downvoted so that the user is confused and starts thinking that he wrote a bad question.

Comment: You assume people are intrinsticly bad, I don't believe that. We don't need to punish them, but guide them in stead, as I propose in my answer and my comment above.

Comment: @Pedro I'm sure most of the people outsourcing their homework to Math.SE already know that it would be considered cheating by their professors.

Comment: There are so we need to be more hard and let them show that we expect effort, for in stance in a bar.

Comment: But what is here being proposed is something totally different. About long term banning? This are really extreme cases. If they see that they don't get answers to their questions they will not ask them again. Also make clear policies: it is not allowed to answer questions that lack effort.

Comment: @Qudit we can not know whether a student gives you a homework question or whether it is an independent learner that tries to answer a question he found in a book, it is also not to us to judge, we don't need to act as a paternalistic organization. We just want no poor questions which show a lack of effort.

Comment: @Qudit Not necessarily true. Some professors *encourage* their students to use Math.SE.

Comment: @BillDubuque I doubt they encourage them to just paste the questions here and copy the answers.  You seem to be arguing against something quite different than what I'm talking about.

Comment: @Qudit I didn't argue against anything. Rather, I pointed out some views on teaching that you might not have been aware of. Please keep in  mind that this is an *extremely diverse* community, and the diversity also holds true for viewpoints on teaching.

Comment: Please define "low quality question"

Comment: @Qudit given how many posters here have difficulty doing this copying *correctly* it might even by a reasonable exercise for some. ;D

Comment: @quid Good point!

Comment: @Pedro "starts thinking that he wrote a bad question": What do you think the downvote means? Downvoting a question isn't a judgment on the person and everything s/he accomplished in her life and their value as a human being, it's simply a judgment on the question they wrote here according to a set of criteria. And sometimes questions don't meet these standards. Let me also add that if low-quality questions were consistently downvoted and closed (before they are answered), users would be less confused and less prone to asking bad questions, because they would only see good questions...

Comment: People often don't know why they get downvoted. I once got downvoted when I was new without knowing why. I thought I wrote a bad question (too trivial) but this was actually not the case. I didn't know I needed to show the work I had already done on the website, because I assumed that most people here would like to answer questions to earn points. A similar person that made this assumption can be found [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1190216/related-rates-question-with-cylinder).

Comment: math.stackexchange fails to make clear to new people why they are writing bad questions, and thinks that there exist only 1 type of people, those who really want to abuse the system and use it as a cheap homework service, such that they don't need to do anything.

Do you really think most people are like that? Of course there are people, but all? We just need to be hard for those that really don't want to collaborate, but we fail to make things clear for those people who actually want to colaborate. The problem is we, not them. We need to look at our own, in stead of cheaply blaming others.

Comment: @Pedro [Let's try to make it clear](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/19938/147263)...

Comment: @Woodface very nice initiative :)

Comment: @Pedro: *I* can’t always tell why a question has been downvoted, and I’m certainly familiar with the usual reasons. In the last month I’ve seen a couple of questions downvoted, each more than once, that were good questions by any standard: they were clear, they were well-formatted, and they showed that the asker had given thought to the matter. Oh, and since some users are prejudiced against really elementary questions, no matter how they’re asked, I should mention that these were hard questions at solid graduate level.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Maybe we should together (with all of us) agree that these sort of questions are allowed then. And add this information to a page with guidelines about how to downvote.

Comment: The same thing happens on stackoverflow, stackexchange people aren't doing anything about it, people eventually give up. Good to see it's not the case here.

Comment: @simonzack People also give up when so many questions are wrongly closed that their is little opportunity left to teach, and when many of their answers from the past end up being deleted due to massive deletion campaigns, and when many of their answers are wrongly downvoted to facilitate deletions, etc, etc.

Comment: Oh there are (plural) massive deletion campaignS now, that's new. Enough of the rhetoric...

Comment: @Najib Thanks for reminding me: add to the above list: incessant nonconstructive heckling by a small number of meta users.

Comment: @Bill: People also give up when so many questions are wrongly reopened and undeleted that there is little distinction from being a mathematical outsourcing service.

Comment: ... and if I could have found all of these "opportunities to teach" amongst the trash, I probably would have longer tolerated the campaign to keep the trash around.

Comment: @Woodface I might take your encouragement to downvote often more seriously if you *upvoted* some as well. As it is, you've cast nearly 19,000 downvotes to only 13 upvotes. With such a record, it does not seem to me that you've genuinely invested much effort to evaluate the content that you see. Furthermore, I would say that the site generally has an upvoting problem as well; there are plenty of high quality answers with very few upvotes.

Comment: @Mark: 40 votes is not many considering the volume of the site and number of questions coming in daily, and downvotes are overall too rarely used, so if one spends some time reviewing low quality content, it can be easy and useful to use all votes as downvotes. True, very few do so exclusively, but there are plenty who exclusively upvote.

Comment: @JonasMeyer 40 votes? Is that the daily maximum?  In fairness, I actually downvote some nowadays precisely because I think woodface has a point. (I think he had a different screen name when I first read his arguments.) I still find it hard to fathom that a 19,000 to 13 ratio arises from a sense of responsibility or tough love.

Comment: @Mark: Yes, 40 is the max daily.   Regarding the extreme case, the way I've seen it described is something like this if I remember right: If downvotes are needed on the site more than upvotes, say they each bring value $A$ relative to an upvote's value $B$ with $A>B$.  Optimizing $Ax + By$ subject to the constraint $x+y=40$ yields $x=40$, $y=0$.

Comment: @MarkMcClure I don't browse the site in any "normal" way; most of my time is spent using the [self-made] tools designed to zoom in on low-quality posts. So I burn through 40 downvotes pretty quickly: right now I'm already out of votes, and there's a lot more in today's crop that I didn't get to.

Comment: @Jonas This isn't totally true. You have $40$ downvotes a day, and you get them back if a downvoted post is deleted during this (vote) day. E.g. If you downvote $40$ times, but before the (vote) day ends, and $10$ of these downvoted questions/answers are deleted, you can reuse those votes(and the count doesn't exclude these) giving you 50 downvotes a day.

Comment: @Jonas: While it’s true that most high-rep users upvote much more often than they downvote, only seven of the $143$ users with $20$K rep have never downvoted.

Comment: @Brian: Thank you for that.  I wonder also about the "almost exclusively".  I am not aware of any users with 20K rep who have never upvoted, but one who downvotes "almost exclusively," I think a number significantly more than 7 who have cast very few downvotes.  I do not know how to look such stats up off hand.

Comment: @Jonas: I did it by hand: I simply looked at all of the user pages involved. And yes, there are also quite a few with upvotes in the high three digits or more and downvotes in the single digits. I know of one, currently suspended, who has $2477$ downvotes and no upvotes; according to [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/289145/top-downvoters) he’s the only user with over $100$ votes and no upvotes.

Comment: @pizza In my view, if a question is interesting enough to answer, then it's probably interesting enough to upvote.  It's rarely the case that I answer a question without upvoting it  You've also answered over 1500 questions yet your down/up ratio is at roughly 20,000/14.

Answer (score 22):

(Disclaimer: this post is cynical and by a poster who is currently not participating in MSE.)

Inertia.

The way the internet works, the all-inclusive viewpoint never had to convince anyone that it was a good idea, or even to get anything near a majority of opinionated people behind it -- all it had to do was to obstruct attempts at pruning MSE until the people who cared got exhausted and gave up trying to make MSE better or quit entirely.

And boy, did they do a good job of being obstructive. They even managed a successful PR campaign to convince the groupmind that "undecided" is synonymous with "all-inclusive", thus paralyzing the people who cared into inaction until a mythical unanimity occurred, which of course can never happen without the consent of everyone promoting the all-inclusive viewpoint.

And the way the stackexchange network is set up, the people who are willing participants in the activities that would otherwise have been pruned away gain reputation, which is a proxy for authority, which means the help vampire problem is even more insidious than in the typical internet community.

I am a once prolific contributor that has quit MSE due to my belief that the situation has become hopeless, and I am not the only one who has done so. While there is certainly a lot more pruning going on today than there once was, the problem is just *too big*.

The triage queue mentioned in the [other answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/19922/14972) is very intriguing, though. Moderating what can even be posted to MSE (rather than after the fact) is a change which is drastic enough to be susceptible to actually achieve something. I really hope it is both effective, and not rendered useless to rubber stamp approvals.

Comment: I think that the important point in this *entire* ongoing war over "the spirit of the site" is that on both sides we have users who put a great deal of hours, and argue their argument because of their passion to the site. It is an unfortunate truth that whatever decision is made (even temporarily), or not made, some of these valuable contributors will leave angrily. It's a sad sad part of life. But that's just how it is. (But regardless, I'm still happy to see your user name on meta.)

Comment: @Asaf Karagila: “some of these valuable contributors will leave angrily.” – You say that like we users are a commodity. I'm starting to realise that I'm trapped in a content factory. Are we not _allowed_ to leave? I'm starting to wonder how one actually quits the addiction after being on Stack Exchange for so long.

Comment: Clearly Stack Exchange will want to have its cake and eat it; they'll want to keep the users on both sides of the fence of the ‘spirit of the site’ war – more users, more money. As a user who puts hours of thought into my posts (not just on SE Mathematics), seeing low-effort homework questions or answers get upvoted while some of my questions that I've put several hours into, _each_, have been heavily downvoted, closed, or deleted – I want out!

Comment: @James: If you were following this meta site closely the past couple of years, you would have seen many arguments I favor and against each side which can be summed up as "That user left just because blablabla". My comment was aimed at the people who have wasted many an hour on these arguments here. Clearly, you're not one of them.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila: I'm sorry for being emotional in those last 2 comments. It's just that I'm finding unconstructive criticism on Stack Exchange sites (particularly Server Fault) rather distressing at the moment, and then I saw this question in the ‘Hot Meta Posts’ box. Seeing low-effort questions being favoured over questions and answers that I put hours of effort into is bewildering and somewhat agitating, like rubbing salt in the wounds. I'm really not sure what to do.

Comment: @JamesHaigh *Seeing low-effort questions being favoured over questions and answers that I put hours of effort into is bewildering and somewhat agitating, like rubbing salt in the wounds.* Sure it is a little distressing that good stuff could get lost in a pile of inferior stuff, but surely the mere existence of inferior stuff should not bother you too much. If it does, then I'm afraid the Internet is not for you :) Take pride in answers you worked hard on and don't Fret about relative attention gotten!

Comment: @JamesHaigh I have to say that I'm a little annoyed, ashamed an disappointed that my most upvoted answer (82 points!) is an answer to some dumb puzzle, whereas some answers that I spent a lot of time writing hardly received any attention. But such is life, and in the end I don't think it's healthy to answer these questions just for the validation it gives...

Comment: @rschwieb: Some corners of the internet do a better job than others of filtering out the inferior stuff.

Answer (score 10):

People have been trying to find shortcuts to doing homework since time immemorial.  That students who are too lazy to actually think would post their homework here is the least surprising fact on earth.  As noted here, there are perverse incentives via the rep/gamification system to answer such questions.  Some of the more clever of the lazy students are doubtless aware of this.

My point is, unless there are fundamental changes to the way SE works, nothing we do is going to stem the tide of such questions appearing at the site.  We have tools at our disposal, as noted here, such as closing for lack of context.  But we are able to dispose of only the most egregious of offenders mainly because of some of our eager answerers.

Although I make efforts to evaluate each question on its merits before answering, I honestly could care less whether [@user8675309](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/867-5309/Jenny) is stymying his or her education.  As I have said many times before, I am here for my own enjoyment.  I am not a tutor: that is a paying job.  Thus, my efforts here go into solving problems I find fun.  That means, many times, I simply don't post a solution.  I solve, and if I post, I will post a bare bones walk-through insufficient for a question poster to understand without work (but sufficient for someone who knows the subject matter to get my point).  Those adverse to any work are quickly exposed as the vampires they are.

I do have one thought, however: the War on Drugs.  You know, where the US Gov't decided it would be a fantastic idea to combat drug addiction at home by establishing a paramilitary outfit to bomb drug suppliers into next week.  No, I am not suggesting that we establish a paramilitary outfit to bomb the vampires' homes as part of a War on Rep.  I am suggesting that, as we've seen happen in our War on Drugs, targeting the askers of Zero Effort Questions (ZEQs) is doomed to failure.  Our efforts, rather, should be focused on the drug (rep) users.

I am going to start down voting answers to ZEQs for which hints have already been given.  To counteract protests that "This answer is correct and is what the OP asked for," I will explain my actions in the comments so that the context is clear.  I propose language such as "Although this answer is correct, such answers encourage the misuse of this site by people who are not interested in Mathematics.  As such answers do harm to the site and the people who care about it, it is only worthy of downvotes."

Maybe rep farmers will not care, as a downvote or two will not affect the amount rep they collect from an accept and uproot from the OP.  However, enough answers with negative scores will help people see where someone's rep comes from, and I assure you, that person will make the effort to reverse that by ceasing the behavior.

As we are many hundreds of humans acting independently, I doubt that such a scheme will stop much of anything.  But even if used on occasion to identify the most egregious farmers, then we will have helped matters a little, without wholesale changing the site.

Comment: "I am going to start down voting answers to ZEQs for which hints have already been given."  Just a clarification:  are you going to downvote answers that provide only hints?

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche: No, I'm not inclined to do that, although maybe I should.  ("Don't feed the animals.")  That said, I wonder what possible useful hint one could provide to an OP whose post essentially says "Help!!  Solve my problem!!"

Comment: While there is a place for hints, often they seem the worst of all to me, as they seem useless for everybody. In addition, the prepending of "**HINT:**" seems sometimes merely (ab)used to deflect  criticism.

Comment: -1 Downvoting fine answers simply because you disagree with the answerer's question selection criteria is an especially terrible idea. This won't have any effect on those answerers (except wrongly denigrating their correct answers so possibly misleading students about its correctness).

Comment: @BillDubuque: Actually, I agree with you.  But that's not what I said.  Rather, I said, "I am going to start down voting answers to ZEQs **for which hints have already been given**" (**emphasis** mine).  This is the opposite of a terrible idea.  I am going to downvote what many people here feel is egregious behavior.  Further, in case anyone may get confused, I will explain precisely what I am doing in the comments.  Nobody who bothers to look should be misled.

Comment: @Ron Still a terrible idea (except possibly if the OP asked *only* for hints). Votes on  answers should not be correlated in any way to perceived deficiencies in the question. Please allow folks to teach as they like. This is a very diverse site, with consequent diversity in teaching styles.

Comment: @Bill: The tooltip says that answers should be voted down if they are not useful. I can very easily see how one might get the idea that supporting and encouraging the practice of posting deficient questions is not useful.

Comment: @Bill: The more one sort of question drowns out the rest, the less diverse MSE becomes.

Comment: @Bill: Also, it would be nice if folks like me were allowed to teach how they like. Alas, all of the deficient questions prevent me from doing so -- and even if I decide to try and teach to those, other people like to teach in a way that prevents me from doing so.

Comment: @BillDubuque: I would love to agree with that attitude.  I have argued that we need ZEQs to some degree because they generate the traffic the site needs to demonstrate growth, etc.  But many ZEQs do collectively harm the reputation of Math.SE so long as we are seen as an easy place to get homework/test questions done for you.  Thus, the measure I have described is one I feel will help the site overall.  I do not intend to just start down voting indiscriminately (see my ratio of down to upvotes, it is small).  <con'td>

Comment: But I do intend to put people on notice that gaining rep off the backs of people who have carefully calibrated their answers so as to help without suborning cheating, etc., is not a good thing.  If enough people do this, it will discourage established users from these sorts of rep-farming activities that harm all of us.  I wouldn't say this unless I have observed this.

Comment: @Ron We need questions that *motivate* answerers. I enjoy certain types of questions like that since they give me more freedom to expound on certain topics (vs. solve it only the OP's convoluted way, which, alas, are more abundant nowadays)

Comment: @BillDubuque: I totally understand.  Some of my favorite answers have come from what are considered ZEQs/PSQs.  But the ones I have chosen to answer, to me, were clearly not homework.  They were just from people who liked to pose hard problems and watch the fireworks.  I love being part of that!  But I also believe in the power of a good hint after I have worked out the problem in full.  I find it extremely annoying when an OP is so lost he just poses a clear HW question - or just asks for a hint - and then some putz answers the whole thing due to some insecurity.  <cont'd>

Comment: So if someone kills a really nice hint by posting a full result, that hurts others.  We don't have to sit and take it.  We have a downvote, and it is entirely valid here.  Actually, I can theoretically downvote an answer for whatever reason I want, just as long as it is the answer I am down voting and not the answerer.  I am saying that I will downvote and make it plain why I am down voting.  I feel I am helping the site by doing this - you feel otherwise.  We'll see.

Comment: @Ron It's not always so clear cut what type of answer is best. I don't think it is fair to ask others to refrain from posting more elaborate answers, esp. if they think the hint is poor, or misleading. One of my pet peeves is users who post guesses as "hints" - many of which lead absolutely nowhere (alas, I've debunked far too many of those). Of course we all make mistakes now and then, but some users do this habitually (usually on topics at the boundaries of their knowledge).

Comment: @BillDubuque: Again, I could not agree more.  I have railed against so-called "hints" in a question dedicated to the problem here:  http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9229/misleading-answers-poor-answers  I personally do not post anything unless I have worked things out in full.  (A few of my earliest answers were premature by my standards now.)  Period.  I will challenge someone who clearly has not thought out their verbiage via comments and downvote.  At least one user I know (who has been suspended for a year) has repeatedly posted useless hints.

Comment: But some hints are really well thought-out and in fact read better than full answers.  (One of my top scoring answers is in fact a hint.  More or less.)  I dislike seeing their effectiveness compromised by an ill-considered full answer.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to show some bar with additional information to new posters that if it considers an exercise/homework question, it is necessary to provide enough context (e.g. where have you found the problem, why do you want to know the answer to the problem) and show the effort they have already done (which techniques do they think are needed, what have they already tried)? And show this information in a colorful banner, and they need to add a check mark to show that they have read this. And also write that the question will not be answered and downvoted or closed otherwise.

I guess most new users just don't know they are doing anything wrong and they suggest that we know all their answers within a milisecond of time, and as such don't need to show their effort.

Comment: Please explain why you disagree when you downvote.

Comment: Why is my opinion down voted so hardly? I really believe making things clear will prevent people for posting questions with a lack of effort.

Comment: It won't. The really bad questions don't come from people with a desire to learn and understand.

Comment: Still this does not solve the problem for those who get downvoted but have a desire to learn. I understand the type of questions you are talking about, but this are maybe only a third of all questions downvoted. For these people the banner will help, because they know now that they can't just be lazy.

Also know that people are not lazy or unwilling to learn by nature usually. It is unfair to think that some people can never be cured. Often those people got raised with media and friends which discouraged learning, hence their behaviour.

Comment: @MarkFantini I ask myself kindly know if you have actually read what I wrote. We give a warning that bad questions aren't allowed. If you don't want to learn, you first need to change your attitute if you want to contribute. Otherwise you just need to stay away. Showing that we actually not appreciate and are really hard for people who do not want to learn and just want to use us as an outsource service for homework problems, will dramatically reduce the amount of bad question.

Comment: At first sight, it is impossible to distinguish between the two. I share some of your ideals, but we need to consider seriously the hypothesis. Do you think this banner would cause the real shift in those people behaviors? Unlikely. I never said that people are unwilling to learn by nature. Unwillingness to learn is strongly correlated to how one has been educated. It can (and often does) change with time and environment you immerse yourself, but to think a banner would cause this is too idealistic. We do give warnings. Some people receive multiple warnings. They are called downvotes.

Comment: I actually believe it will. If the user needs to consciously indicate that he read what was inside the bar and will post a quality question and accepts the fact that he will be punished and get no answer if not, less people will post a bad question. My guess: only 10-15% of the people that pose bad questions will keep doing this after the update, the vast majority will not.

Comment: If people had a willingness to read beforehand, they would probably browse the help and the site overall looking for good examples. Either way, unless your suggestion is implemented we will never know. Until a better alternative comes up, downvoting is the way to go. If you want to encourage new users with a heads-up you can comment on all the questions you think the OP may change its ways because of what you are pointing to.

Comment: I actually never read any guidelines or read any of the questions when I asked my first questions.

Comment: Is this something to boast about?

Comment: That doesn't mean you shouldn't have (when you joined), nor that new users shouldn't. Most, like you, do not read the guidelines or any questions, but they should (at least) be encouraged to do so, specially if their questions are subpar for the site.

Comment: No, I just want to show that some people don't read the guidelines before they post. I posted on stackoverflow before though (on an other account). And on stackoverflow I read a lot of questions, never read guidelines, but it was quite okay my question since I read quite a lot on stackoverflow.

Comment: @Mark: In point of fact some of the really bad questions *do* come from people who show evidence of wishing to learn and understand, because they engage productively when given a hint.

Comment: @Brian: And I'm always curious how many of those examples would have *started* with a better post (and possibly leading to an exemplary question/answer pair rather than protracted discussion), if they weren't led to believe that there is no reason *not* to post a really bad question, or even that that's what they're "supposed" to do. (and, usually, going to extreme measures to avoid false negatives usually results in an unacceptable false positive rate -- and I see no reason to believe that doesn't apply here)

Comment: @Hurkyl: I don’t really care. Besides, I think it likely that many people learn more from the questions and answers, and I’m more interested in what the OP learns than in abstract archival value.

Answer (score -2):

The problem is caused by the flawed educational system in the US and some other countries where students are given homework assignments that are going to be graded. That's a stupid system, because you learn better from hard problems that are not so suitable for such assignments (hard problems that even good students will struggle doing will be impossible  to grade). Students will then spend a lot of time doing the assignments perfectly, it's then very tempting to post such assignments here.

The way to end this problem is to raise the problem not here, but at your own institutions. Instead of giving your students graded homework assignments, just tell your students that if they are not seriously practicing doing the suggested hard problems, they'll fail the exam and that may have rather nasty consequences. What we'll then see here are students who are stuck but who want to learn how to do the problem instead of asking us to do the work for them.

Comment: Ignoring the question of whether the education system is flawed or not, the fact is that it isn't going to change for the benefit of Math.SE, so Math.SE needs to cope with the current environment.

Comment: @Qudit: So does the system, and the current environment includes numerous resources for getting any amount of help with homework. It always has done; the main effect of the internet has been to make level the playing field a bit in that respect. There is a place for graded homework — a very modest amount in routine courses like calculus, and a more substantial amount in theory courses, in which learning to write mathematics is an important part of the course — but outside sources of help aren’t a problem when it’s used properly. (And yes, I speak from experience.)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I think it ought to be acknowledged that some others who also speak from experience still see this differently. (In fact, I not so much, but it still should be acknowledged.)

Comment: The comment thread got a bit out of hand with too many re-runs of opinions/points-of-view that had been exchanged umpteen times earlier. Deleting them, as it was becoming personal.